# Login with Twitter using Swift and OAuth in ios

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-oauth

I am very new to Swift and IOS. I want to implement the login with twitter account using OAuth in my swift iOS application.

I implemented it but I got

> [{“message”:”Could not authenticate you”,”code”:32}]}

error

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite heavy to implement OAuth of the twitter to the iOS. In my applications I am using `ACAccountStore` for authentication with the twitter. For you I can recommend to use [this](https://github.com/nwalter08/SimpleTwitterReverseAuth) library.

Comment: could you give me a library in Swift?

Answer (score -1):

Too Easy

I used framework [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) which is very nice. also watch this video [Twitter app only Authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKiRRWjZWmQ) and check STTwitterDemoiOS demo to more clear.

Step 1: Create Twitter app and get Consumer key and Consumer secrete.

Step 2: Download STTwitter Framework and Drag and drop file into your Xcode project.

Step 3: UIWebView/Safari Login

```
- (IBAction)signInWithTwitterClicked:(id)sender {
    //login by website
    self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:CONSUMER_KEY
                                                 consumerSecret:CONSUMER_SECRETE];
    [_twitter postTokenRequest:^(NSURL *url, NSString *oauthToken) {
        NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
        NSLog(@"OauthToken: %@", oauthToken);
       // if(1) {
         //   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        //} else {
        //WebViewVc taken from STTwitterDemoiOS  demo.
            WebViewVC *webViewVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebViewVC"];
            [self presentViewController:webViewVC animated:YES completion:^{
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
                [webViewVC.webView loadRequest:request];
            }];
       // }
    } authenticateInsteadOfAuthorize:NO
                    forceLogin:@(YES)
                    screenName:nil
                 oauthCallback:@"myapp://twitter_access_tokens/"
                    errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"-- error: %@", error);
                      //  _loginStatusLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
    }];

}
```

//Step 4 and Step 5 imp to callback to our application

Step 4: Configured info.plist as shown in image.[image]

Step 5: Handle application Delegate method

```
    - (NSDictionary *)parametersDictionaryFromQueryString:(NSString *)queryString {

        NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        NSArray *queryComponents = [queryString componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

        for(NSString *s in queryComponents) {
            NSArray *pair = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if([pair count] != 2) continue;

            NSString *key = pair[0];
            NSString *value = pair[1];

            md[key] = value;
        }

        return md;
    }


    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
             annotation:(id)annotation
    {
        //Twitter integration

       // if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myapp"] == NO) return NO;


        NSDictionary *d = [self parametersDictionaryFromQueryString:[url query]];
        NSString *token = d[@"oauth_token"];
        NSString *verifier = d[@"oauth_verifier"];
       // NSLog(@"Twitter Token=> %@\n Twitter Verifier=>%@",token,verifier);
        ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
        StartupViewController *startVc=(StartupViewController *)[[vc childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
        [startVc setOAuthToken:token oauthVerifier:verifier];

//startVc is my controller where my "Login with twitter" button is there.

        //if no Facebook integration then return YES instead if return    //[FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

 //Facebook Integration 
        return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    }
```

Step 6: Get User credentials.

```
-(void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier {

    // in case the user has just authenticated through WebViewVC
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
       //Dismiss presented controller.
    }];

    [_twitter postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {
        //Here is your Ans.
        NSLog(@"SUCCESS screenName: %@ ,userID=%@", screenName,userID);

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

hope this help some one.

Comment: Thank you for your step by step explanation but your video link called "Twitter app only Authentication" is not working could you comment the correct video link again

Comment: could you give me step by step for Swift not in objective C?